# Slide Down to Show More Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Ok, so I know I've done this before, but I'm two days back from a really long cycling trip and I can't remember the best way to do this. But I have a some content that I'm wanting to have a link to slide down to show more.

I have a demo here:
https://codepen.io/ultraloveninja/pen/VGORZN/

Which *sorta* does what I want it to, but I'm not 100% sure what I would need to use a `slideToggle` instead of just hijacking the CSS and adding the height to expand it down.

Here's my JS:

```
 $(".show-more").on("click", function() {
    $(".items").css("height","100%");
  });
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.items {
  height:100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.show-more {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thing">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p>A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p>All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p>A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p>All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p>A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p>All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
 <a class="show-more" href="#">Show More</a>
```

Again, I'm trying to get it to animate like a `slideToggle` or something to that effect. Just not sure if it's better to do something, like, tack a class on it and do a `toggleClass` instead or if there's a better way to possibly go about it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ckmxg2zL/

Answer (score 1):

[.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) may be the method you are looking for. Here is my solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show-more").on("click", function() {
    $(".extended-content").slideDown(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.items {
  height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.show-more {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.extended-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="thing">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p>A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p>A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
      <h2>This title</h2>
      <p>A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. Words are like wind. And now his watch is ended. Bastards are born of passion, aren't they? We don't despise them in Dorne. King in the North.</p>
      <p class="extended-content">All men must die. It's ten thousand miles between Kings landing and the wall. A good act does not wash out the bad, nor a bad act the good. Each should have its own reward. The wolf and the lion. All men must die.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
 <a class="show-more" href="#">Show More</a>
```

I have added `height: 100%` to `.items` and I have added the class `extended-content` to the `p` elements which has the property `display:false` and will be shown with a slide down animation effect when `#show-more` is clicked.

Comment: Hmm, ok cool. Yeah, I'll mess with this and see what I can come up with. Thanks!